# How do I maintain two different iOS devices on a single iMac

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, mac-appstore, sharing

My wife and I share an iMac, and our iPhones keep populating with each other's apps. iTunes keeps trying to update my phone with my wife's apps and data. Is there a way to update the settings on the phone so it can distinguish the difference between App Store accounts?

Comment: Do you change login @ iTunes when you connect your phone? Or do you keep logged in either one of you?

If you login yourself before connecting your iPhone it most likely won't put applications on it from your wife.

Comment: I see. We don't have separate logins on iTunes on the MacBook Pro and just open it up. Is there a way to delete her apps off my phone. As much as I adore her I don't want affirmations and yoga mood colours or ladies underwear popping up when I am with clients.

Comment: Try logging in your own application and remove the application you don't want via iTunes. They won't sync back on then. If this doesn't work there is an option that you create a second account on your iMac and sync both from different accounts. Guaranteed no mixing up.

Comment: You need to make a new OSX account on the Mac and have one for you, one for your wife. Each OSX account will have it's own iTunes prefs so it will be easy to just fast-switch to your account and know that iTunes will know all about your iPhone. You can share a single credit card if you like, or keep things totally separate.

Answer (score 5):

Easy way: create multiple user accounts on your Mac, a tutorial can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph6651).

-or-

Hard way: create different iTunes libraries for your user account.  You'll need to:

- Quit iTunes
- Hold down the Option key and then launch iTunes
- Click the "Create Library..." button on the dialog that is displayed
- Once you've created the different libraries, you need to remember to use the Option key and then "Choose Library..." to switch between the two **every time** you start iTunes

A multi-part tutorial can be found [here](http://ipod.about.com/od/advanceditunesuse/ss/Multiple-Itunes-Libraries-One-Computer.htm).

Comment: It'd be much better to just use two user accounts.